# Kubernetes cluster with firewall enabled on CentOS(calico) not working

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I've bringing up Kubernetes cluster with calico as CNI on CentOS 7 with firewall enabled. I've master and worker nodes. I was able to bring up cluster and able to list the nodes and Kubernetes system pods, all are working fine. However I'm unable to perform dns lookup.

**System configuration**

> Kubernetes: 1.21.1 
> Calico: 3.19.1 
> Docker: 20.10.5 
> CentOS 7.9 
> IPVS enabled 
> Using VXLAN based network in Calico

**Firewall configuration**

- The ports I've enabled are.

  ```
  - 6443/tcp
  - 2379-2381/tcp
  - 10248-10260/tcp
  - 30000-32767/tcp
  - 8285/udp
  - 8472/udp
  - 7946/udp
  - 7946/tcp
  - 7472/tcp
  - 7472/udp
  - 9100/tcp
  - 443/tcp
  # cAdvisor Port
  - 4149/tcp
  # calico
  - 179/tcp
  - 4789/udp
  - 5473/tcp
  - 9099/tcp
  - 9099/udp
  ```
- The enabled `masquerade`
- Added interfaces `kube-ipvs0`, `vxlan.calico` and `docker0` to trusted zone (Though was unable to add cali* interface to trusted zone as I was unable to add regex based interface rule)

The Problem is `DNS` lookup doesn't work. Tried following steps to identify `iptables` lookup.

- Installed DNS debugger pod

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: dnsutils
      namespace: default
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dnsutils
        image: gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3
        command:
          - sleep
          - "3600"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
```

- Enable firewall debugging on worker node on which pod got scheduled

```
    firewall-cmd --set-log-denied=all
    firewall-cmd --reload
```

- Now run `nslookup`

```
    $kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
```

result:

```
   ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

   command terminated with exit code 1
```

- Get the rule that rejected the packet

```
    dmesg | grep -i reject
```

result:

```
    [ 5556.708338] FINAL_REJECT: IN=calib3c61c3cba9 OUT= MAC=ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:de:c8:d5:97:58:87:08:00 SRC=10.244.212.65 DST=10.96.0.10 LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=49835 PROTO=UDP SPT=52743 DPT=53 LEN=70
    [ 5561.707815] FINAL_REJECT: IN=calib3c61c3cba9 OUT= MAC=ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:de:c8:d5:97:58:87:08:00 SRC=10.244.212.65 DST=10.96.0.10 LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52640 PROTO=UDP SPT=52743 DPT=53 LEN=70
    [ 5566.708055] FINAL_REJECT: IN=calib3c61c3cba9 OUT= MAC=ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:de:c8:d5:97:58:87:08:00 SRC=10.244.212.65 DST=10.96.0.10 LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54942 PROTO=UDP SPT=52743 DPT=53 LEN=70
```

Comment: Is `coredns` running and healthy?

Comment: @whites11 yes, I don't see any errors. Note when I stop and disable firewall everything starts working

Answer (score 1):

cali* interfaces can be achieved using "+" wildcard:

```
name=kubeAccept
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=${name}
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=${name} --set-target=ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=${name} --add-interface=vxlan.calico
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=${name} --add-interface="cali+"
```

Tested and works in AlmaLinux 9 or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue recently and it took us time to find what the actual problem is.

##### Problem

Even when you add ports for calico it does not work because, when you explicitly add port to firewall it blocks all other ports across interfaces. And calico creates a new network interface(vxlan.calico) which needs to be added to firewalld

##### Symptom

One symptom we noticed due to this was, we were able to ping pods across nodes. So icmp was working but tcp/udp did not work. Most likely you will get the same symptom.

##### Solution

You will need to add the network interface created by calico (check ifconfig to get exact name) to a trusted zone in firewall or create a new zone for it.

Create new zone and adding interface to it:

```sh
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone={name}
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name} --set-target=ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name} --add-interface=vxlan.calico
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Note - you will need to do above steps for master as well as all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the following steps.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone={name}
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name} --set-target=ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name} --add-interface=vxlan.calico
```

Then I looped through the calico network interfaces

```
for i in $(ip a | grep cali | awk -F":" '{print $2}' | awk -F"@" '{print $1}') 
do 
  sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone={name} --add-interface="$i"
done
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I suspect that the looping through the cali* interfaces may not work, because as far as I can tell, they will be added (and removed?) dynamically.